# "in/as accompaniment to/of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-of

I would like to write the correct form of the following sentence:

> He played the guitar in/as accompaniment to/of the choir's chant.

Which is the most correct, and why?

Comment: Why was this question down-voted? Down-voting isn't corrective unless you explain the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

He played the guitar in accompaniment to/with the choir's chant.
He played the guitar as an accompaniment to/with the choir's chant.

Answer (score 1):

*Accompaniment to* is more widely used than *accompaniment for*. (See this [Google Ngram.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accompaniment+to%2C+accompaniment+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) )

Merriam Webster's example sentences for [accompaniment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accompaniment) are:

```
She sings without musical accompaniment.
A nice tie was a fine accompaniment to his new suit.
This dish can be served as an accompaniment to most meat main dishes.
This wine is a good accompaniment for spicy foods.
She studied Italian as an accompaniment to her classes in art history.
```

The choice of *as* or *in* preceding the words *accompaniment to* seems to be less well defined. (See [this Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+accompaniment+to%2Cin+accompaniment+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), with *as accompaniment to* slightly more preferred.

My preference would be:

> He played the guitar as accompaniment to the choir's chant.

(I [being an editor] would also ask if you might not be able to rephrase the sentence to:
*He accompanied the choir's chant on his guitar.*)

Answer (score 1):

How about just **He played guitar to the choir's chant**? When you play an instrument **to** another performer, you are accompanying and the other performer is playing lead. The expression *to play second fiddle to someone* uses the same form.